# hide/show multiple button in repeater?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have hiden delete buttons"imgbtnDeleteGroups" to delete item in the  repeater but my problem my "btnDeleteGroups" is not showing the imgbtnDeleteGroups

```
<div class="Group">
    <div class="row-fluid">
            <h3 class="font-black">Groups</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid bottom clearfix group-div">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnAllGroup" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnAllGroup_Click"
        CssClass="btn lts-darkgray">All</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptGroup" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptGroup_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="GroupLink btn lts-blue">
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGroupID" runat="server" Value='<%#  Eval("GroupID") %>'
                    />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="GroupBTN" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">
                        <%# Eval( "name") %>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDeleteGroups" CssClass="btnDelete hideDeleteBtn"
                runat="server" CommandName="deleteGroup" ImageUrl="~/DesktopModules/ResourceGrouping/img/off.png"
                ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <div class="groupName">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtbGroupName" runat="server" placeholder="New Group"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCreateGroup" runat="server" Text="Create Group"
            OnClick="btnCreateGroup_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btn lts-green group-dropdown"
            />
            <input id="btnDeleteGroups" type="button" name="" value="Delete Group"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="divbreak">
            <img src="/DesktopModules/ResourceGrouping/img/divbreak-white.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
  $("#btnDeleteGroups").click(function () {

      //alert("sdvsd");
      $("#Group").find(".btnDelete").removeClass("hideDeleteBtn");

  });
```

Comment: Can you show what HTML is generated vs asp.net? This will help since you are using `.js`

Comment: Also with using an ImageButton can you verify that you have the correct path of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no need to reference `.Group` at all unless it is only specific to that portion of the webpage.

If you would like to find them all you should make use of the `.each()` function.  Here is a simplified example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#btnDeleteGroups').click(function() {  
        $('.btnDelete').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("hideDeleteBtn");
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6kUE/1/) to show what needs to happen.

Comment: I just got idea from this, I removed a class on hide: method of jQuery repeater.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code, I see `<div class="Group">`, so `"Group"`is a CSS class and not an HTML ID.
So you should write `$("div.Group .btnDelete").removeClass("hideDeleteBtn");`.
Note that you can fuse `find(".btnDelete")` to your jQuery selector.

Comment: This is exactly my point : he has write `$("#Group")`, but its HTML code need him to write `$(".Group")` or `$("div.Group")` to match the first DIV.

Comment: Sorry I see where you were going, yes that is part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a repeater I would assume it appends the repeater name to the controls and since you will have multiple instances of that control you need to specify which one you are referring to. So something along the lines of

```
$("#btnDeleteGroups").click(function(){
    $("#rptGroup_imgbtnDeleteGroups_" + position).removeClass("hideDeleteBtn");
});
```

would specify that the imgbtndeletegroups that belongs to a certain row was pressed and you want to remove the class from that specific control.

Comment: Wasn't sure if he was using the click statement in his code to just remove from all or just from specific row. If he wants to remove from all then `each()` would be the thing to use.

Comment: where are you defining `position`?